# An example of continuationToken with Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory to get the status of the Pipelines that run in a day. But, I got only the first 100 rows I read that with the parameter `continuationToken`.

You can access the next page do you have any example of how I can put this parameter below is my code in python.

```
url_datos =  "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01"
response = requests.post(
    url_datos,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ bearer},
    data=[('lastUpdatedAfter', date_fin),('lastUpdatedBefore',date_ini),('continuationToken','true')])
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the continuation_token when you have the next page of results, if any remaining results exist, null otherwise.

Here is an example of its usage, however I currently don't have enough pipeline runs to show the token itself.

In Python I used it

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential 


subscription_id = "b83c1wd3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2b83a074c23f"
rg_name = "My-rg"
df_name = "ktestadf"

tenant_id = "12f978bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47"
client_id = "a71ad3ca-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-af0c2a3fdae1"
client_secret = "Nym7Q~j5YMyxxxxxx3tAk879y9vLrxAQqaI8n"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id,client_id=client_id ,client_secret=client_secret)

adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient( credential=credential,subscription_id=subscription_id)

pipe_run = []
dsb = datetime.now()
dsa = dsb - timedelta(hours = 24)
filter_params = RunFilterParameters(last_updated_after=dsa, last_updated_before=dsb)
pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(resource_group_name=rg_name, factory_name=df_name, filter_parameters = filter_params)
pipe_run.append(pipeline_runs.value)
while (pipeline_runs.continuation_token):
   filter_params = RunFilterParameters(last_updated_after=dsa, last_updated_before=dsb,continuation_token = pipeline_runs.continuation_token)
   pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(
   resource_group_name=rg_name, factory_name=df_name, filter_parameters=filter_params)
   pipe_run.append(pipeline_runs.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the documentation [ADF rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/querybyfactory).

What it says is that "continuationToken" is optional when making the first call. If there are more responses/pages to be fetched, you will receive the continuationToken in the response. See [ADF pipelinerunsqueryresponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/querybyfactory#pipelinerunsqueryresponse).
When you make the next call, pass the "continuationToken" in the body equal to the value which you received in the response from the 1st call.

So if you receive "continuationToken" = "ABC" in the response of the 1st call, make another call and pass "continuationToken" = "ABC" in the request body. You can keep doing this until you get a "continuationToken" = null in the response which means you've reached the end of the results.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/querybyfactory#pipelinerunsqueryresponse

Answer (score 0):

The continuation token in ADF is not working as expected, I did try using Sphere-Continuation as well, if someone has cracked this mystery do let us know.

I did test this out using Postman util. This is a bit disappointing due to the lack of clear documentation or a working example. A very critical feature missing.

[image]